# React Native component position not working

Tags: react-native, flexbox

[image]

I'm new to React Native.I need to move email field to upper position in the screen.I tried different ways but I could not get better result. Here I attached my style code.

```
     return (
          <ImageBackground
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#ccc',
              flex: 1,
              position: 'absolute',
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}
          >
          
          <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Email"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               />
          </ImageBackground>
        );
      }
    }
    
export default AuthScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    input: {

        margin: 15,
        height: 41,
        borderColor: '#979797',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius:4,
        backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF',
        shadowColor: '#000000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.8,
        shadowRadius: 2,
        elevation: 1,
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add/change this properties in your ImageBackground:

```
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center'
```

It should work

EDIT for your second question:

I really recommend you to check out [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html) for learning the basis of FlexBox with React. Also, I suggest you to wrap and group your items inside a View component (import it from 'react-native'). So, first wrap your TextInput with a View with this style:

```
     <View
       style = {{
         width:'100%',
         marginTop: 'your_margin',
         alignItems: 'flex-start'
       }}
      > 
       <TextInput style = {styles.input}
           underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
           placeholder = "Email"
           placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
           autoCapitalize = "none"
           />
     </View>
```

Then add the desired width property to styles.input

Comment: Hi Gustavo,
Really Thanks for the solution.now my element in the top but it's width is got shrink.How I solve it and I need to add margin to top.So which style should I change?

Comment: Thank you .Solved !